# To Shade the Area Between $x^2$ and $\sqrt{x}$

Tags: pgfplots, plot, fillbetween

I want to draw the following image in tikZ

[image]

Basically I want to draw the boundary of the unit square, plot the `x^2` and `\sqrt x` functions, and shade the area between them.

In my attempt to draw the two curves, I tried this

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\pgfplotsset{ticks=none}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,]
\addplot[name path=F,black,domain={0:5}] {sqrt x};
\addplot[name path=G,black,domain={0:5}] {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But the output I am getting is

[image]

Somehow the `\sqrt{x}` function is getting flattened out.

Also, how to get rid of the arrows I have in the axes and make an enclosing box like I have in the hand-drawn picture.

Comment: Note that the intersection of curves happens for `x=1`. So change domain to better visualize.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: `sqrt x` should propbably be `sqrt(x)`

Comment: @marmot That does not make any difference.

Comment: @dexteritas I did not know about the etiquette you mentioned. But it makes a lot of sense. Thanks. I have edited my post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Adaptions:**

- Set `min=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=1` to get the desired area of the plots.
- Remove `axis lines=middle` to get default axis (rectangle around plots).
- Use `\addplot [fill=blue!10] fill between[of=F and G];` to fill area between plots `F` and `G`.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\pgfplotsset{ticks=none}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=0,xmax=1,
    ymin=0,ymax=1,
    samples=500,
]
    \addplot[name path=F,black,domain={0:1}] {sqrt x};
    \addplot[name path=G,black,domain={0:1}] {x^2};
    \addplot [fill=blue!10] fill between[of=F and G];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{ticks=none}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,]
\addplot[name path=F,black,domain={0:1},samples=50] {sqrt(x)};
\addplot[name path=G,black,domain={0:1},samples=50] {x^2};
\addplot[pattern=vertical lines] fill between [of=F and G];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]